# How do I use the same fragment for three tabs with different content?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an enum describing three different sports:

```
public enum MatchType {
    S1(0, "Sport1", "xml stream address", R.id.match_list, R.layout.fragment_match_list, R.color.separator_sport1),
    S2(0, "Sport2", "xml stream address", R.id.match_list, R.layout.fragment_match_list, R.color.separator_sport2),
    S3(0, "Sport3", "xml stream address", R.id.match_list, R.layout.fragment_match_list, R.color.separator_sport3);

    ...getters/setters

}
```

I then have fragment with

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    matchesArrayAdapter = new MatchListAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Match>());

    return inflater.inflate(matchType.getLayout(), container, false);
}
```

Also in my fragment I have an AsyncTask where I have this

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final List<Match> matches) {
    if (matches != null) {
        matchListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(matchType.getRId());

        [setup listeners]

        matchesArrayAdapter.matchArrayList = matches;
        matchListView.setAdapter(matchesArrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
In my Activity I have an AppSectionsPagerAdapter with

```
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    MatchListSectionFragment fragment = new MatchListSectionFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(Constants.MATCH_TYPE, i);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here's my onCreate and onCreateView from my fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    matchType = MatchType.getMatchType(bundle.getInt(Constants.MATCH_TYPE));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    matchesArrayAdapter = new MatchListAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Match>());
    return inflater.inflate(matchType.getLayout(), container, false);
}
```

The AsyncTask reads an xml stream for each of the sports in my enum but my problem is that tab #1 is overwritten with data from tab #2 and subsequently tab #3.

Before I had a fragment defined for each sport but surely that can't be necessary?

How do I go about using the same fragment with the same layout for each sport?

Answer (score 2):

When instantiating your fragment in your Activity set the Fragment's arguments with a Bundle.

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putInt(MY_EXTRA, 1);
myFragment.setArguments(myBundle);
```

In your bundle put some Extra that will be read in the fragment's onCreate() callback.

```
int i = getArguments().getInt(MY_EXTRA);
```

Comment: Could you have a look at my edit in my original post? This is what I have at the moment. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Yes, then in your fragment read the MATCH_TYPE int from getArguments() and do work accordingly.

Comment: But this I already do with matchType = MatchType.getMatchType(bundle.getInt(Constants.MATCH_TYPE)); Still doesn't work...

Comment: I assume bundle is the fragments arguments? I don't see why it wouldn't work then. This is how I do it for unlimited number of similar fragments. Use debug mode to check that your values are being sent correctly, maybe check your savedInstanceState info also?

Comment: Sry what's savedInstanceInfo? And how do I check it?

Answer (score 0):

I am on mobile.
Put three FrameLayouts in a LinearLayout, named frame1, frame2 and frame 3. This will be your main Activity's layout.
Then in the Activity's oncreate() method, call getFragmentManager().getFragmentTransaction().
Instantiate the three fragments and send them the data, preferably through a Bundle. 
On the Fragment Transaction call the add() or replace() method for each fragment, the first parameter is the id of the respective FrameLayout, the second parameter is the fragment itself.
Call commit().

Comment: I really want this to work with any number of fragments without having to specify a fragment for each entry in my enum. I want this to be as dynamic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the newInstance method in your fragment, also you should store MatchType instansce in you fragment.

```
MatchType matchType;

public static MyFragment newInstance(MatchType matchType) {
          MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
          fragment.matchType = matchType;
          return fragment;
}
```

In your Activity you should to create 3 instances of MyFragment with this method (with related to each fragment it owns MatchType). Then in onCreateView method you should insert data to your views from matchType.

Sorry, I'm on mobile. And sorry for my English.

**Update**

Check your variable **matchType**. Maybe it declared as **static**?

Comment: I have added EDIT 2 to my original post as it is now - not working :-(

Comment: Maybe your variable **matchType** declared as **static**?

Comment: Nopes. Declared as private MatchType matchType = null;

Comment: Thanks a million voltazor. Will have a look when I get home :-)